# How to send html table as form input in javascript form post to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to send html table as form input using a javascript form POST. Post request is received in the servlet, however I am only getting part of the input table is "table id=". Please help me resolve this issue.

**Javascript code:**

```
    var htmlFormat =  $.trim($('#report_table').html()).split("+").join("%2b");
    var form = $('<form action="./csvReportDownload" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8">' +
              '<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="' + $('#user_id').val() + '"/>' +
              '<input type="hidden" name="new_tokens_dv" value="' + htmlFormat + '"/>' +
          '</form>');
          $('body').append(form);
          $(form).submit()'
```

**Servlet code:**

```
    String param_DETAILS = "report_table";
    String temp = null;
    if (request.getParameter(param_DETAILS) != null) {
        temp = new     String(request.getParameter(param_DETAILS).getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "UTF8");
        log.info("Parameter value: "+temp);
    }

    Console Output: Parameter value: <table id="
```

Comment: you need to use a backslash "\" to escape the double quote

Comment: @vickisys: yes this would escape the double quotes. However I realised the issue is with the websecurity tool kit. Antisamy is blocking my data because of the html tags

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?